# Help understanding simple circuit - ADC0803LCN

Tags: voltage, adc

Would someone mind having a look at the circuit below and explaining in very simple
terms :) what the circuit below is doing. Circuit is taken from the ADC0803LCN datasheet.
Looking in particular at the area within the red box - Span/2 = 2V

Probably not relevant but I'm trying to adjust the analog input range of the ADC0803LCN from 0-5V to 0.5-4.5V.

[image]

Comment: This isn't meant to be at all snarky, but why are you using an 0803? I'm amazed that National is still even making them! If you're trying to get full resolution over a smaller range, it would be simpler to move to a 10-bit device.

Comment: Hi Lyndon, ADC0803LCN is handy for me to get, and I'm connecting it to a low cost (project obj. is low cost) National Instruments I/O device and unfortunately I do not have enough I/O line availability for 10-bit. But I understand your point, I think they have been around since 2002 and older.

Comment: Quite a bit earlier than that! I *stopped* using the 0831 in product back around 1997. IIRC, the ADC08xx series has been around since the early 80's if not before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The marked portion of the schematic is a voltage follower, a k a unity gain buffer. This presents a very high input impedance to the signal source, and a low output impedance towards its load i.e. any following stage. Output voltage of the op-amp precisely tracks input voltage.

In this particular case this voltage follower takes as input the voltage seen at the wiper of the potentiometer, and outputs the same voltage at the output, adding in a bit of low-pass filtering courtesy the 300 Ohm resistor and 0.1 uF capacitor. Thus the output is smoother and less prone to high frequency noise.

The reason it is needed here: If one were to directly connect a load of, say, 300 Ohms, between the wiper of the potentiometer and ground, this would act in parallel with the potentiometer, dragging its resultant voltage down below the desired `SPAN/2`. By loading the wiper with a very high impedance load, i.e. the op-amp, such change in the desired potentiometer output is avoided.

Comment: Thank you both for your answer, nice simple speak :), thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

In the shown circuit the ICL7611 is setup as a unity gain voltage follower. It's function is to buffer the FS adjustment pot so that variation of current draw on the Vref pin does not cause voltage shifts of the reference voltage. If Vref was connected directly to the adjustment pot then variations of current will change the voltage due to the resistors of the pot and end point guard resistors.

The R/C filter following the ICL7611 is used to smooth the reference voltage out. The possible need for this filter could be to remove any effect that power supply noise to the opamp could have on the opamp output. Another value to the filter is that it smooths the transition of the Vref so that it does not have sharp edges that could occur if there was any noise generated as the FC adjust pot was moved/turned.

Now all that said one could wonder about why there is not a similar buffer shown for the ZERO adjustment pot. Possibly omitted if the current level on the Vin- is very low.